# UWP Can't convert from StorageFolder to StorageFile

Tags: c#, file-io, uwp, uwp-xaml

so I'm trying to write a simple app that will let me create a text file with some content and file name then save it to a file, which can then be re-edited later. However for some reason I am getting 2 errors being new to c# and the whole UWP I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong any help with the following to errors is much appreciated.

```
    private async void writebutton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String fileName = txtFileName.Text;
        String text = txtContent.Text;
        StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
       (51) StorageFolder file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
       (52) await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, text);
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("File saved" + fileName);
    }
```

First error (line 51): Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.Storage.StorageFile' to 'Windows.Storage.StorageFolder'

Second error (line 52): Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Windows.Storage.StorageFolder' to 'Windows.Storage.IStorageFile'

Comment: I guess your problem is related to line 51. File (change this name!) is defined as a Folder and not as a file, but in line 52 you treat it as a file.

Comment: OMG I feel like a butt not noticing that... thanks much!

Comment: You're welcome... All of us face things like that...  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the problem.

```
(51) StorageFolder file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Change this to

```
(51) StorageFile file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Comment: Thanks much, feel pretty dumb not seeing that thanks much!

Comment: No worries my friend. We've all been there.